# Chef- Cannot Setup Mysql Error : Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, chef-infra

I have been struggling with this for quite some time now. Can't provision vagrant. Problem seems to lie with the way i am using mysql. I am using the community mysql cookbook.

Error:

```
==> default: Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[install-grants]'
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default:
==> default:
==> default: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
==> default: ------------------------------------
==> default: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
==> default: ---- Begin output of /usr/bin/mysql -u root -prootpass < /etc/mysql_grants.sql ----
==> default: STDOUT:
==> default: STDERR: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
==> default: ---- End output of /usr/bin/mysql -u root -prootpass < /etc/mysql_grants.sql ----
==> default: Ran /usr/bin/mysql -u root -prootpass < /etc/mysql_grants.sql returned 1
==> default:
```

Comment: Check that you have the latest version of the `mysql` cookbook, I know there were several new releases in a short timeframe.

Comment: Checked, using the latest version

Comment: I thik I had this kind of problem when wrapping the cookbook and using a default['mysql']['server_root_password'] because the recipe does a set to register it. In my wrapping cookbook I had to use override IIRC.